# Scrolling windows with wxPython

Tags: python, image, scroll, wxpython

I am making a frame with a scrollbar and some images inside. The scrollbar works fine when the frame is empty. However, when I add a picture in, the scrollbars seem to get pushed up into the top left corner of the frame. How can I implement my code so that the scrollbars stay where they are after I add pictures?

Working Code;

```
    import wx
    import wx.animate


    class ScrollbarFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Scrollbar Example', pos = (100, 50), size=(1000, 1000))
            self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
            self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1000, 1000)
            #self.button = wx.Button(self.scroll, -1, "Scroll Me", pos=(50, 20))
            #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,  self.OnClickTop, self.button)
            #self.button2 = wx.Button(self.scroll, -1, "Scroll Back", pos=(500, 350))
            #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClickBottom, self.button2)
            self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
            imageName = "01 background.png"
            gifName = "Jill.gif"
            backgroundImage = wx.Image(imageName, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, backgroundImage,(10,5),(backgroundImage.GetWidth(), backgroundImage.GetHeight()))
            gifImage = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, 0, gifName, pos=(160, 74))
            # clears the background
            gifImage.GetPlayer().UseBackgroundColour(True)
            gifImage.Play()

    def update(self, imageName, gifName):
        backgroundImage = wx.Image(imageName, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, backgroundImage,(10,5),(backgroundImage.GetWidth(), backgroundImage.GetHeight()))
        gifImage = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, 0, gifName, pos=(100, 100))
        # clears the background
        gifImage.GetPlayer().UseBackgroundColour(True)
        gifImage.Play()

    def OnClickTop(self, event):
        self.scroll.Scroll(600, 400)

    def OnClickBottom(self, event):
        self.scroll.Scroll(1, 1)


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = ScrollbarFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

---

if you comment out this part:

```
 gifName = "Jill.gif"
        backgroundImage = wx.Image(imageName, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, backgroundImage,(10,5),(backgroundImage.GetWidth(), backgroundImage.GetHeight()))
        gifImage = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, 0, gifName, pos=(160, 74))
        # clears the background
        gifImage.GetPlayer().UseBackgroundColour(True)
        gifImage.Play()
```

the window displays properly with the scrollbar. But include either (or both) of the image files, and the problem occurs.

Comment: If [this other question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469975/making-a-scrolling-frame-in-wxpython) is superseded by this one, you should probably delete it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your images inside the scrolled window panel, then you have to put your static bipmap and gifImage inside it. So the parent of your images should not be `self` (the `wx.Frame` instance) but `self.scroll`.

Modify the 4 lines indicated:

```
    ...................
    wx.StaticBitmap(self.scroll, -1, backgroundImage,(10,5),(backgroundImage.GetWidth(), backgroundImage.GetHeight()))    # <- this one
    gifImage = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self.scroll, 0, gifName, pos=(160, 74))  # <- this one
    # clears the background
    gifImage.GetPlayer().UseBackgroundColour(True)
    gifImage.Play()

def update(self, imageName, gifName):
    backgroundImage = wx.Image(imageName, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    wx.StaticBitmap(self.scroll, -1, backgroundImage,(10,5),(backgroundImage.GetWidth(), backgroundImage.GetHeight()))    # <- this one
    gifImage = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self.scroll, 0, gifName, pos=(100, 100))  # <- this one
    ...................
```

This puts your two images one over the other. If you want to put them separately (column or row), then you should add them to a sizer inserted in your scrolled window